# How to cancel a request in BeforeSendRequest

Tags: .net, wcf, iclientmessageinspector

When using the `IClientMessageInspector` interface, can I cancel a request from the `BeforeSendRequest` method? Returning `null` sends the request anyway.

```
 public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
 {
    if(Condition)
    {
        return null; //I want cancel my send
    }
    else
    {
       return request;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever solved this? I'm looking at the same issue and I'm not finding anything to cancel the request without sending body

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the request with IClientChannel's Abort method. But your client's dispatch method throws **CommunicationObjectAbortedException**.

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
 {
    if(Condition)
    {
        channel.Abort();
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
       return request;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to handle this scenario, but I think they all involve simply throwing an exception out of your IClientMessageInspect.BeforeSendRequest to prematurely end the client operation.  The type of exception you throw probably varies depending on what the consuming application expects in your scenario, or something you can catch upstream some where else.

In my case, I was building a WCF RESTful proxy/routing service. My IClientMessageInspect was required to inspect outgoing messages bound for our texting vendor, and not allow the outgoing message to be sent to the vendor's Service API unless the outbound phone number was "white listed" in the router proxy/routing service web.config

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    if (!WhiteList.IsWhiteListed(outboundNumber))
    {
        throw new WebFaultException<RouterServiceFault>(new RouterServiceFault {Message = $"Phone number {outboundNumber} is not white listed." }, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }

    // Save the routed to service request address so we can see it after receive reply (in correlationState)
    return request.Headers.To;
}
```

Where RouterServiceFault is a simple class I can pass a message back in to display/log in the consuming application.

```
[ServiceContract]
public class RouterServiceFault
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```