# WCF Client single point to block/filter outgoing requests

Tags: wcf

I am looking for a single point in a WCF client, where I could filter outgoing requests. I am injecting user session info into my requests' header, and in case user session info is unavailable, I would like to block/abort the message from being sent. I have looked everywhere, and couldn't find a decent solution. I have a IClientMessageInspector, which is responsible for injecting the session info, but I can find no way to abort a message from the IClientMessageInspector.

There is unanswered question from 2 years ago, on how to cancel a message from IClientMessageInspector: [How to cancel a request in BeforeSendRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696750/how-to-cancel-a-request-in-beforesendrequest). This is not a duplicate, since I am also open to better/other ways of achieving a single point of client side message filtering, and not necessarily through IClientMessageInspector.

Things I have tried so far:

- Turning the request to null, generates an exception.
- Closing the request, using request.Close, generates an exception.
  (I have actually looked at a decompiled source of RequestChannel class, to see if it has any way that it will just abort the message, without throwing an exception, and couldn't find a way).
- Closing/aborting the channel, generates an exception.
- Couldn't find a way to hook into the error handling, in order to block one of the above exceptions, like you could do on the server side using IErrorHandler interface.
- Tried overriding the request, and making it an empty request, got 500 error from server

Just for reference this is my BeforeSendRequest (IClientMessageInspector):

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        if (UserContext.CurrentUser != null && UserContext.CurrentSessionId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            var headerToAttach = new RequestObject()
            {
                UserId = UserContext.CurrentUser.Id,
                SessionToken = UserContext.CurrentSessionId
            };

            var wcfHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("SessionHeader", "sessions", headerToAttach);
            request.Headers.Add(wcfHeader);
        }
        else if (request.Headers.Action.Split('/').Last().ToLower() != "login")
        {
            // How to abort the request?
        }

        return null;
    }
```